# In laravel 5.8, we are unable to save sessions using user other then www-data

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, php-7.2

We are using laravel 5.8 and PHP 7.2. The issue we are facing is when, starting server using below command, session is not working:

php artisan serve --host=IPADDRESS

But the same is working fine with www-data user, if we place our source code in /var/www/html folder.

Using php artisan command we are accessing the project on 8000 port, where sessions are not working. I tried to add my user to www-data group but still I am unable to get this work.

Please someone help here to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'php artisan serve' from a specific login it most likley may not have appropriate permissions to write files to the folder sessions are being stored.

Check path set in session.save_path (in the php.ini file that is used) and check it's permissions.